# FullCalendar.js - Schedule behind an editable eventSource

Tags: fullcalendar

I developed an application in which employees input their work day.
My boss asked me to add their schedule as a watermark behind.
Schedule is a different events source that can not be changed, unlike working days.
Inputs of work days must not overlap, but must cover the schedule (hide it).

I have not found how to prohibit overlap within the same source while allowing it between different sources.
I also do not know how to make sure that in place of an overlap, I have a covering.

Thanks.

Comment: in the Select callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) you can write whatever code you like to test overlaps between whichever events you decide to look at. If you don't like the overlap you can cancel creation of the event (and you should validate this on your server-side too whenever an event is created or edited, in case someone tries to bypass the GUI). Have you tried to do anything yet? I also don't know what you mean by "I also do not know how to make sure that in place of an overlap, I have a covering." Can you clarify?

Comment: I just don't want that : [link](https://ibb.co/i5xb75)
The darker events need to be over the lighter ones.

Comment: you don't have control over that, sorry. fullCalendar decides how to arrange them. The only thing you can do is, if you know in advance which events you are making the "lighter" events, you can declare them as "background" events. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/ However, the only downside is that background events don't have their time or title displayed on the calendar by default.

Comment: Thanks you, that's perfect for one of my two issues. I'll dig into the select_callback documentation for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ADyson for his help.

So the answer to my question is :

```
eventSources: [
    {
        id: 'employee',
        events: <the_ajax_code>,
        overlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
            return stillEvent.source.rendering == 'background';
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'schedule',
        events: <the_ajax_code>,
        editable: false,
        rendering: 'background'
    }
]
```

The employee event source events can only overlap events from the schedule event source.
The schedule is render in background.